# universal crossplatform App for Android, iOS and PC - theoretical

Tags: android, ios, vb.net, cordova, cross-platform

I'm currently working on a project and I need to develop the same app for Android smartphones, iOS gadgets(iPhone/iPad) AND a normal desktop computer with Windows. It could have been easy, but my boss who is kinda far away from programming wants all of them to be written in the same language to have only one source-code with minor changes for all 3 Apps. I told him it's hardly possible and now trying to find the most shortest ways. What I have now:
 1. To write everything using HTML, CSS and JS - suits for Android and iOS using for example PhoneGap... but with the .exe version I'm in the deadend. I was considering using VB's WebBrowser, but it uses the installed version of IE... doesn't pass me. And now the hardest moment: once a day I need to localy store a copy of a DB with about 20k entries and then read them. Not really a problem for smartphones, I've tried something similar before, but on a computer, localy, from an IE powered VB Client... I think it's impossible at all.
 2. The same for smartphones, but pure VB for the computer version.

Could you please suggest some other options (shorter and faster than writting 3 native apps) or mby offer me some suitable tools or APIs I don't know yet.

Thank you!

Comment: We don't know what you know, so we can't recommend tools you don't know yet. Why don't you google the topic -- this has been asked and answered at least a dozen times on SO, even though it's entirely off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Write a single page web application.

- Embed it in a browser in Android.
- Emded it in a browser in iOS.
- Embed it in a browser on Windows.

On Windows it doesn't have to be IE. There is several way to embed a browser into an application. One I could suggest.

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-declarative-webbrowser.html
- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-webview.html

Qt provide a webview based on WebKit (Used by Chrome and Safari), so it should have all the modern features you expect.

Answer (score -1):

I have heard about those tools, but never tried yet

- Phone Gap (HTML/CSS/JS)
- Xamarin Tools (C#)
- appceleration titanium (JS)